# asp.net MVC - Can I reference views from a class library?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, class-library

In an asp.net MVC application, is it possible to reference views from a class library in the same way that it's possible to reference a class library of server controls or user controls in Web Forms asp.net?

I've seen this blog post: http://padcom13.blogspot.com/2009/04/splitting-aspnet-mvc-application-into.html, although the method described involves copying the views to be re-used into the application.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: My **guess** is that you would have to customize the default view engine to look for the the views in the class library in addition to the standard ~/Views directory. Not something I've tested.

Comment: @Nathan - yeah, that's what the blog post says.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oops! Sorry I couldn't be more helpful. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it would be theoretically possible if you use a custom view engine which loads the templates from within the class library.

This approach, however, seems rather *wrong*. If you want to create an analogue of server controls, your best option is to implement them as Html helpers, as the MVC team already started. A shameless plug - you could look at the open-source [Html helpers for jQuery UI](http://telerikaspnetmvc.codeplex.com/) that were built by Telerik - they use the outlined approach.